# Expected value and Poisson random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be a Poisson random variable with $E[X]=\ln(2)$. Calculate $E[\cos(\pi X)]$.

Is it as simple as putting in $\ln(2)$ as $X$ in $\cos(\pi X)$?

I feel there is more to the problem but am unsure where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\cos(\pi \ln(2))$ would be wrong: $E[f(X)] \ne f( E(X))$ in general for nonlinear functions $f$.

One way is to use the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29) of the Poisson distribution.  Another is to sum the series:

$$ E[\cos(\pi X)] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda} \dfrac{\lambda^x}{x!} \cos(\pi x)$$

where $\lambda = \ln(2)$, noting that $\cos(\pi x) = (-1)^x$ for integers $x$.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped, especially the latter part with the set-up equation.